# How to show the correct frame based of the changed current time of video

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using an HTML video tag. I'm changing the video's current time based on hovering on the customized seek bar, the current time is changing but the frames are not changing smoothly. I found that seeking that changed time is taking time, is there a way we can fast seek?
This is the code I'm using to change the seek time

```
const videoSeek = (e) => {
    const ratio = e.offsetX / videoContainer.offsetWidth;
    const seekto = video.duration * ratio;
    video.currentTime = seekto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slider for seek bar i.e. input tag with type="range"

```
<input type="range" id="seekSlider" min="0" max="100">
```

and listen for 'change' and 'movemove' event on the seekSlider eg.

```
$('#seekSlider').on("change mousemove", function() {
    const sliderVal = $('#seekSlider').val()
    video.currentTime = totalDuration*(sliderVal/100); 
});
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing is with the smoothly changing video frame without getting stuck based on the change in currentTime

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand it. Can you create a jsfiddle and share it